# The map collection declared by apex is not accepted by lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, sobject, sobjectfield

The map collection declared by apex is not accepted by lwc.

Schema to get all field names corresponding to the object.I made apex code using SObjectType.
System.debug was used to verify that there were no errors in the code.

However, I tried to get this data into lwc, but the data could not be read.

Please let me know why...

Here is my apex code

```
public with sharing class BB_DataDwonLoaderFields {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, Object> getAllFields() {
    
      Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> contract = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
      for(Schema.SObjectField fields :contract.get('Contract').getDescribe().fields.getMap().Values()) {
          System.debug('Contract '+ fields.getDescribe().getName());
      }

  return contract;
    }
}
```

Here is my lwc code

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import getAllFields from "@salesforce/apex/BB_DataDwonLoaderFields.getAllFields";

export default class childCmp extends LightningElement {
  childValue;
  @api objectValue;
  @api strAccountName;

 get optionsValue() {
    return [
      { label: "notEquals", value: "notEquals" },
      { label: "isNotNull", value: "isNotNull" },
    ];
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    getAllFields()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("제발!!!", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain on what are trying to achieve

Comment: Oh.. Thank you for the comments!! When I selected an object from a combo box in the parent component, I wanted to show the fields related to the selected object in the combo box in the child component

Comment: Instead of returning the whole `Schema.getGlobalDescribe`, you should have your own map with just the required data and send back? Like `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: Did you get some error message? If so, please **[edit]** your post to include its text verbatim.

Comment: @Adrian Larson Thanks for your comments!! I coundn't get any error message though!

Comment: @Raul Thanks for your help! I'll do it with  "Schema.getGlobalDescribe"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe`, you can just:

```
  for(Schema.SObjectField fields :sObjectType.Contract.fields.getMap().Values()) {
```

This is much more efficient, and your page will load much faster.

But... you don't need Apex at all. Just use [`getObjectInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info):

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CONTRACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contract';
```

...

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTRACT_OBJECT }) contractObject;
```

The `contractObject` will have a property called `data`, with an inner property called `fields`, that will list all the fields and their data types.

Read the documentation for more information.